# Document outline in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've seen that Atom has a HTML document outline extension which seems to give you a good picture of your semantic HTML. Is there an equivalent in VS Code?

Answer (score 15):

VSCode has a built-in outline view [as of 1.25.0 (June 2018)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_outline-view). There are two ways to open it:

- View  → Open View...  → Outline
- Run the `Explorer: Focus on Outline view` command

[image]

Currently the location is restricted to the file explorer, but there are [plans to make it more flexible](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49923).

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2023 you can add an Outline to the secondary view as well:

- press `CTRL + SHIFT + P`
- Toggle Secondary View

Then drag the `Outline` onto the secondary view.